# background-image & background-color in a div with IE

Tags: css, html

I have a little issue related to mixing `background-image` and `background-color` in a div holder.

The div looks like this:

```
<div class="board_position" x="1"  y="1"></div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.board_position {
width:25px;
height:25px;
margin:1px 0 0 1px;
float:left;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;

background: #f4f4f4; /* Old browsers */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f4f4f4 0%, #ffffff 23%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f4f4f4), color-stop(23%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f4f4f4 0%,#ffffff 23%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f4f4f4 0%,#ffffff 23%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f4f4f4 0%,#ffffff 23%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f4f4f4 0%,#ffffff 23%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f4f4f4', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

The `board_position` class draws a rounded box with a gradient background-color.

Some divs with that class have additional properties which I supply by adding another class to that div. This additional class is only a `background-image`:

```
<div class="board_position bg" x="3"  y="1"></div>
.bg { background-image:url(/img/bg.png); }
```

In Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera it works fine.

But in IE the result is a squared box (not rounded) and in the `board_position` divs which have additional properties added with another class, the image loaded is not shown because it seems that the image is under the `background-color`.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE? CSS 3 attributes like border radius are not functional in older versions of IE and result in square corners. Secondly your css selector .bg and .border_position have the same rule of important so the last one in the css will win so if you list bg first then board_positon, board position will win. to make sure .bg wins add more to the selector like .board_position.bg now this has importance of 020 and the bkg will overrule .board_position which has a value of 010.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and under does not support rounded corners.

Try using http://css3pie.com/

Please remember to use the fixes in http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support rounded borders. As for the other issue, remember that the image path is relative to the CSS file, not the file that links it.

Comment: IE 9 and 10 do. Not sure abt 8